# iOS project changed to macOS and unable to compile code

Tags: xcode

Buildi info : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYfT1.jpg

The base SDK is set to iOS. But unlike before, I am unable to select iOS version instead it forces macOS on me. I think this is the reason I am unable to compile and get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC6EQ.jpg

Attempted: Restart XCode. Switch to macOS and back to iOS.

EDIT: looks like all my other projects are set for macOS now. All of them have iOS as selected build settings and deployment target. Don't know why it is not syncing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an XCode update that prevents the APIs from linking up. I guess is Apple's way of blocking outdated xcode versions. I had to force quit xcode and all other projects running on Xcode. Then re-open xcode and the update for v.12.3 prompts and now everything is back to normal.

If you get the error, chances are your xCode is out of date because apple released a new version very recently. Try everything to find/ get it to update.